# How can I pipe a scp copy from a machine to another?

Tags: scp

Let’s say we have three machines: A, B and C.

- Machine A can't reach machine B from any network, so I can't send files between both.
- But both A and B can be reached from C (my machine).

Today I have to copy a huge file from A to B.

Currently I would need to copy it first from A to C and then from C to B. Is there a way to connect or pipe the `scp` to stream the incoming data to the target machine without need to save in the middle?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`man scp` writes (with my emphasis)

> **`-3`** Copies between two remote hosts are transferred *through the local host*. Without this option the data is copied directly between the two remote hosts. [...]

So what you need is a copy command that routes via your local system (I almost always include `-p`, to preserve timestamps and permissions, so I've done that here too):

```
scp -3p serverA:path/to/file(s) serverB:/path/to/destination
```

Very recent versions of `scp` have `-3` [enabled by default](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/bfdd4b722f124a4fa9173d20dd64dd0fc69856be) since 9 August 2021, and to disable it one must now specify `-R`. Using this third party copy feature will disable prompts for passphrases and passwords as `scp` cannot ask for them for both hosts.

Answer (score 1):

`scp user1@A:from_file user2@B:to_file` should do the trick. Read `man scp`.

Comment: It expands to `ssh user1@A "scp from_file user2@B:to_file"`

Comment: @Vlad I think your tip will make A send file to B but as I said there is no network between   both

Comment: @MagnoC I know, this tip expands the answer of waltinator.

Comment: The whole point of the question seems to be that this method doesn't work.

Comment: However, as mentioned in the other answer, recent versions of `scp` use `-3` mode by default, in which case this should work.

Comment: @Barmar as I can see this method (not this answer... I'm refer to Vlad's tip above) connect into "A" terminal (SSH) and then issue a SCP to "B" (using its location scope) what AFAK will not work because "A" can't reach "B" directly as I pointed in my question. Please correct my thought. This answer is correct since it respect the "-3" condition.